# $P = I − uu^T$ when $u$ is a normalized vector (subtraction of scalar from matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector $u$ that is normalized (i.e., $||u||_2=1)$. This means that

$$
uu^T = ||u||_2^2 = 1
$$

Does it make sense to define $P=I-uu^T$ given that $uu^T$ is a scalar.

What does it mean to subtract a scalar from a matrix?

Comment: The usual convention is that $u^T u$ is a scalar, $uu^T$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with components $u_i u_j$.

Comment: If you did mean $P = I - u^T u$, then a "matrix minus a scalar" really intends for that scalar to be multiplying the appropriate identity matrix, so $P = I - u^T u = I - u^T u I = (1- u^T u)I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a column vector with $n$ columns, then $\|u\|^2_2=u^Tu$, but $$uu^T = \begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\ \vdots\\ u_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1&u_2& \dots& u_n\end{pmatrix}$$ is a matrix whose $ij-$th entry is $u_iu_j$.

Consequently, $I-uu^T$ has $1-u_i^2$ on the diagonal and $-u_iu_j$ as $ij$-th entry if $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 1):

$uu^T$ is a matrix. Looks like you’ve confused it with $u^Tu$, which is scalar.